# Can I use the same podfile (cocoapods) for a project that has both iOS and tvOS Targets?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cocoapods, tvos

I am trying to create a tvOS version of an existing iOS app that I have, and want to be able to reuse a lot of the same code (i.e. 3rd party libraries, data managers, etc) so I am using the same .xcworkspace with just an iOS target and a tvOS target.

Since I use cocoapods for all 3rd party libraries, and will need to reuse some (not all) of them for the tvOS app (i.e. Parse), I want to know the proper way to integrate cocoapods with my project.

I am getting this error when trying to compile for tvOS target, but not the iOS target:

```
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

**And yes, I have tried all the usual cleaning the project, deleting the .xcworkspace, rerunning pod install, etc.**

My podfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.1'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use link_with to specify multiple targets for your podfile to link against.

Example:

link_with 'MyAppTarget', 'MyTvTarget'

Comment: Yeah its doable using this method, so correct answer. Personally I ended up creating a separate app just for the tvOS app, as there were too many conflicts and easier to manage as a separate project.